# Как создать точный автоматический коллайдер Rigidbody2D тела?

Tags: unity3d

Нужен точный коллайдер для 2д тела. Хотел использовать полигоновский, но он настраивается вручную. Где-то слышал, что можно преобразовать спрайт в 3д модели и использовать Rigidbody3D + Mesh Collider, но не хочется заморачиваться с 3д, да и придется все спрайты в 3д переделывать(или нет?)

Comment: Если спрайт состоит из 2х полигонов, то вы "не в ручную" это не сделаете.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел бесплатный [плагин](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/52265) в Asset Store. Есть возможность настроить точность